# How should I approach calculating sample size for number of raters required for a study?

Tags: sample-size, agreement-statistics, artificial-intelligence

I am proposing a study for evaluating reports generated by 3 human experts vs 3 different LLMs on a set of 10 situations. Basically, we're trying to whether the human experts are better or if the LLMs are better (and if so, which LLM is best).

The proposal committee explicitly asked for a sample size calculation for the number of raters we will need. Each report will be rated in 5 categories on a scale of 1-5 (ideally we'd like to be able to report which performer is best in each category). However, I'm unsure how to approach doing the sample size calculation for this (I initially thought I could get around this by saying that we'll get at least 10 raters, but they explicitly want a sample size calculation).

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should be doing a power calculation on? Would it be inter-rater reliability here and if so, what is the formula for it (I know how to program in R and can use any packages that would be helpful).